How I can compute the trace of double Lie derivative.
Let $X$ is a smooth vector field on a Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$.
We know that the trace of $L_X g$ is equal to $\operatorname{div} X$.

I want to compute the trace of $L_X (L_X g)$?

Any hint is highly appreciated.

First compute $\mathcal{L}_Xh$ for a symmetric $2$-tensir $h$. Then use that formula.

Thank you. Can you please send me the details of the final result?

You should try to do it yourself

If $X=X^k\partial_k$, and $h$ be a 2-symmetric tensor, then $tr(L_Xh)=g^{ij}X^k\partial_k h_{ij}+2g^{ij}\partial_iX^k h_{kj}$. But I do not know the global formula of this.

Write the formula for just $\mathcal{L}_Xh$. In local coordinates. Nothing wrong with doing that. No trace.

In this case, we have: $L_X(L_Xg)= X^k \partial_k (h_{ij})+ 2 \partial_i X^kh_{jk}$

Replace $h$ by its value on left.

Thank you again. I obtain  $L_X(L_Xg)= X^k \partial_k (L_X g){ij}+ 2 \partial_i X^k(L_X g){jk}
$. For tracking, I know the first term is equal to $2X. div X$ but I have no idea for the second term. I think it is related to 1-1 tensor field corresponding to $L_X g$.

Replace $L_Xg$ by its formula.

Let's start from the beginning: Could you provide a formula for $L_Xh$ in terms of $X$, $h$, and their partial derivatives only? No $g$.

Yes. We can write $L_Xh=X^k\partial_k h_{ij}+2\partial_i(X^k) h_{kj}$.

No, that's incorrect. $L_Xh$ is a symmetric tensor, but your formula is not symmetric in $i$ and $j$. Perhaps you could show how you computed this.

Yes, I am wrong. The corrected formula is $L_Xh=X^k\partial_k h_{ij}+\partial_i(X^k) h_{kj}+\partial_j(X^k) h_{ki}$

Yes. Now check that the formula still works if you replace each $\partial$ by $\nabla$ where $\nabla$ is the Levi-Civita connection of $g$.

I think it is true. If we consider the normal coordinate at a point $p$. Because the both sides are tensorial.

Ok. Now use that twice to get the formula you want.

Thank you. I do not understand. Is it possible to give me some more hints. Now, I need to sum over index $i$? Is it correct? In fact, I need to compute $\sum_{i=1}^n X^k\nabla_k h_{ii}+\nabla_i(X^k) h_{ki}+\nabla_i(X^k) h_{ki}$.

You have a formula $$ L_Xh_{ij} = X^k\nabla_kh_{ij} + \nabla_iX^kh_{kj} + \nabla_jX^kh_{ik}. $$ You can use this formula to get a formula for $L_X g_{ij}$. Now set $h_{ij} = L_Xg_{ij}$ and substitute the second formula into the first.

Thank you. I did the computations, finally I derive local terms which I do not know their global formula.
